# Attaching a new reference to an array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array that accepts 3 `parameters`: `Employees(firstNames, lastNames, idNumbers)` which are string arrays.

```
String[] firstNames= {"Fred","John","Amir", "James","Bob","Jay","Amber"};
String[] lastNames = {"Bond","Kates","Memar", "White","Marley","Brown","Nogofski"};
String[] idNumbers = {"R111111","A222222","AB11111", "KR22121","V311133","L242434","P102432"};
String[] employeeNum = {"1111","2222","3333", "4444","5555","6666","7777"};
```

When i call my printing method i get the output:

```
First name: Fred
Last name: Bond
Id number: R111111
Employee number: No employee number has been assigned yet!

First name: John
Last name: Kates
Id number: A222222
Employee number: No employee number has been assigned yet!
```

and so on...

As you can see there is no employee number yet assigned. However when i use my `assignEmployeeNum()` method, the Employee number should change to the number in the string array:

```
String[] employeeNum = {"1111","2222","3333", "4444","5555","6666","7777"};
```

But instead i get this output:

```
+++After adding the employee number to the list+++

First name: null
Last name: null
Id number: null
Employee number: 1111

First name: null
Last name: null
Id number: null
Employee number: 2222
```

and so on...

my initial attempt at this problem was just adding another constructor specifically for the employee number but clearly that didn't work. any advice would be appreciated.

**main method**

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
String[] firstNames= {"Fred","John","Amir", "James","Bob","Jay","Amber"};
String[] lastNames = {"Bond","Kates","Memar", "White","Marley","Brown","Nogofski"};
String[] idNumbers = {"R111111","A222222","AB11111", "KR22121","V311133","L242434","P102432"};
String[] employeeNum = {"1111","2222","3333", "4444","5555","6666","7777"};

Employee[] list = new Employee[firstNames.length];
list = listOfEmployees(firstNames,lastNames,idNumbers); // create the list of employees in one array
printEmployeeList(list); //print the list of employees
list = assignEmployeeNum(list,employeeNum); // assign the employee number to the employees
```

**Employee Class**

```
public static class Employee{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String idNumber;
    private String employeeNumber;
    private int employeeCount;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param firstName first name
     * @param lastName last name
     * @param idNumber id number 
     */
    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName, String idNumber){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.idNumber = idNumber;
        employeeCount = 0;
    }

    public Employee(String EmployeeNum){
        this.employeeNumber = EmployeeNum;
    }
    /**
     * Accessors here
     */

    public String getFirstName(){
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName(){
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getIdNumber(){
        return idNumber;
    }

    public String getEmployeeNumber(){
        return employeeNumber;
    }

    // mutators here

    /**
     * @param firstName first name
     */
    public void setFirstName(String firstName){
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    /**
     * @param lastName last name
     */
    public void setLastName(String lastName){
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    /** 
     * @param idNumber id number
     */
    public void setIdNumber(String idNumber){
        this.idNumber = idNumber;
    }

    /**
     * @param employeeNumber employee number
     */
    public void setEmployeeNumber(String employeeNumber){
        this.employeeNumber = "";
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        String result = "\nFirst name: " + getFirstName() + "\nLast name: " + getLastName()
                + "\nId number: " + getIdNumber() + "\nEmployee number: ";
        if(getEmployeeNumber() == null){
        return result + "No employee number has been assigned yet!\n";
    }
        return result + getEmployeeNumber() + "\n";
    }

}
```

**Assign employee method**

```
public static Employee[] assignEmployeeNum(Employee[] list, String[] number){
for(int i = 0; i<list.length; i++){
       list[i] = new Employee(number[i]);
}   
 return list;    
 }
```

Comment: An array cannot accept parameters. `Employees(firstNames, lastNames, idNumbers)` looks like a constructor call on a class named `Employees`, but you have no such class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a completely new Employee object within the assignEmployee method, one with null values for every field, rather than using the one that already exists in the array. Solution: don't do that. Instead take the current Employee object held in the array at that position and simply set its employee id in your method.

e.g.,

```
public static Employee[] assignEmployeeNum(Employee[] list, String[] number){
    for(int i = 0; i<list.length; i++){
       list[i].setEmployeeNumber(number[i]);
    }   
     return list;    
 }
```

Comment: hmm now when i changed the code to that everything prints but the employee number. it just remains blank, perhaps something wrong in my `toString()` method?

Comment: @Deescomaster: you need to learn to debug. Look at your setEmployeeNumber method -- it's broken as you're setting nothing.

Comment: you're ignoring the method's parameter.

Comment: @Deescomaster: no problem, but the bug should point you where to look. If you're not able to see a change in the employee id display, then the problem is either with the display or the setting methods.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
list[i] = new Employee(number[i]);
```

You need to use

```
list[i].setEmployeeNumber(number[i]);
```

With your code you create a new Employee object which has just the employee number.
With the modified code you use the existing employee and set the employee number.

Comment: Your setEmployeeNumber method is not correct as well, it just writes a blank into the field.